# JMeter - using substring on a user variable

Tags: javascript, substring, jmeter

Using jmeter, I have a variable passed from CSV file (using CSV Data Set Config), and I'd like to use a substring of it in an http request.

i.e.
variable TIME=23:40, request paramaters are hour and minute, so I want to extract appropriate parts, in the HTTP Request.

I read you could use javascript, so for the hour, I tried  `${TIME}.substring(0,2)` , which didn't look as though it would work, and sure enough it didn't.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do that by calling javascript function inline http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Ex :

```
${__javaScript('${TIME}'.substring(0\,2))}
```

Or

1. create user defined variables sample
2. create variable called myTime(or anything you want)
3. create beanshell sampler, choose beanshell as language in it then:

   ```
   String tempTime = vars.get("myTime");
   String newTime = tempTime.substring(0,2);     
   vars.put("newTime", newTime);
   ```

use `${newTime}` variable in your request

Edited according to the other answer. Comma needs to be quoted.

Comment: Great, thanks, was probably being a bit lazy - I did RTFM, but didn't really understand what it meant. Cheers

Comment: @Joe Watkins np, jmeter is a gr8 tool it just has poor documentation in my opinion

Comment: Ant, please correct the quoting of the comma. It mislead me, when I used your solution. Thanks, Gábor. So to make it work, you need ${__javaScript('${TIME}'.substring(0\,2))}

Comment: @ant Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/URsAFM? Please I really need some help

Answer (score 7):

You can do it without calling Javascript interpreter (Rhino) with [substring](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/Functions#substring_since_0.4.2) function from JMeter plugins:

```
${__substring(${TIME}, 0, 2)}
```

Comment: This answer is true in that substring is a custom jmeter function, but note that it is just a wrapper around js String.substring. Docs here: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#substringsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup. I like this answer just for readability/simplicity though.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you escape commas in javascript functions:

```
${__javaScript('${TIME}'.substring(0\,2))}
```

Comment: Probably should have been a comment on c0mrade's answer.

Comment: I edited the accepted answer. If it passes the review, it will be visible.