# How to extract substring data from Json response using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

My Json response is:

```
"return":"/info?booking=KD6YGS4L8I"
```

Now I want to extract value after "=" (ex:"KD6YGS4L8I").
I used Regular Expression extractor:
- Regular Expression: "return":"(.+?)"
- Template: $1$
- Match No: -1

And output is:

```
"return":"/info?booking=KD6YGS4L8I"
```

Now I want to get string `KD6YGS4L8I`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression: `booking=(.+?)"`, with template `$1$`. Match Number (n) depends on your needs:

- n > 0: matches the given occurence number,
- n == 0: matches a random occurence,
- n < 0: matches all occurences, and organizes them with subvariables.

See [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) on JMeter website.

I suggest you to take a look at the following guides:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html),
- [how to use JMeter Regexp Extractor](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/09/07/jmeter-regular-expression-extractor/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a Beanshell sampler as a sibling to your Regular Expression Extractor with the below code:

//Assuming your regular expression extractor variable is RegExpResult

```
String regExpResponse= ${RegExpResult};
String[] result= regExpResponse.split("=");
result[1].replaceAll("\"", "");
vars.put("BookingValue",result[1]);
```

Now BookingValue variable contains - KD6YGS4L8I

You can find the same issue been resolved in stackoverflow:
[JMeter - using substring on a user variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266018/jmeter-using-substring-on-a-user-variable)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi @Dinesh: I try to print value "returnLink" out, but  it's cannot . It's show error: